# Data compression to reduce network bandwidth usage

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, compression

suppose that I've a huge amount of data (>KB/MB) to transfer from an ajax request (JS) to a webpage (PHP), is it usefull to deflate data (by JS scripting) before send it to server and inflate it in my Webpage or the Apache module (Content-Encoding:gzip) do it by itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content Compression offered by apache will only compress data sent from server to client.

For you to compress data that you are sending to the server would involve a lot of effort which i am not sure will be worth the effort.

you could try using a js data zip api like http://jszip.stuartk.co.uk/

Comment: Seems not be true, I used Wireshark and the answer sent back from server contain data like I sent it in my Webpage. Is my use of Wireshark to abusive ? I checked out your link and it seems not be working with IE, and my users only use IE ...

Comment: Data sent from server when compression is enabled works without any issues, i have tried it on IIS. I think you have missed out something in your configuration. try implementing one of the basic compression algorithms like (Huffman) this should be pretty straight forward.